# Plotting a third variable against x and y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am very new to R and I am trying to plot a third variable to a plot using ggplot2. I have searched for an answer and I could not find anything similar (or I didn't know the right words to search).

I have three columns of data which will be my x, y and z variable.

I want a graph that can show the values for  x and y axis (as in the first and second column variables). **However**, I want the "points" (as a scatter plot) in the graph to be the values shown in variable z. Is there a way of doing that?
Everything that I have tried plot x against y.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think a sketch, or an excel plot, of what you want would help. I'm not sure my answer is what are looking for.

Comment: I tried to upload a figure but I still don't have permission for that. I think I want to do something as adding a series in excel. Imagine I have the value for x = VirusProbabitlity1, for y=VirusRate1. What I want to plot is the value of z = 0.0015.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is what you are asking: Map two variables: (x,y) in their axis and display the "text" of a third variable. 
Let's use this data frame - We'll try to "write" X1 and X3

```
df <- data.frame(X1 = 1:5, X2 = 2*1:5, X3 = rnorm(1:5))
```

With **base graphics** you can just plot one character

```
plot(df$X1, df$X2, pch = paste(df$X1)) plot(df$X1, df$X2, pch = paste(df$X3))
```

doesn't seem to work well.

Using **ggplot2:**

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = X1, y = X2)) + geom_text(label = df$X1)
ggplot(df, aes(x = X1, y = X2)) + geom_text(label = df$X3)
```

a fancier alternative is adding colour in the aes()

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = X1, y = X2, color=X3)) + geom_text(label = df$X3)
```

Comment: Thanks! I end up doing a contour plot... I don't want to map (x,y) in a plot. But I would like that values of z to be associated to (x,y). I tried to use what you suggested to my data, but because I need to use something similar to facet_wrap, I'm getting an error message.

Comment: Ok. That´s perfect. Maybe you could answer your own question with what you ended up doing.

Answer (score 3):

> I want the "points" (as a scatter plot) in the graph to be the values shown in variable z. Is there a way of doing that?

Definitely. The bit that you need to think about is how to present the data in your `z` variable. By that I mean do you want the information in z to be shown by the points' colour, size or area? There are some great examples of how to do this at [the R cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/).

If you have a data frame called `my.data`, which has columns `x`, `y`, and `z`, you need to set up your plot like this:

```
my.plot <- ggplot(data = my.data,
                  aes(x = x,
                      y = y))
```

The example above says "plot the data in `my.data` using `my.data$x` to set the x location and `y.data$y` to set the y location". If your x variable was `grid.x` and y was `grid.y` you would have

```
my.plot <- ggplot(data = my.data,
                  aes(x = grid.x,
                      y = grid.y))
```

then you need to add your points. This time we'll assume that the information in `z` is going to used to set the colour of the points, which in this case is the `colour` aesthetic:

```
my.plot <- my.plot + geom_point(aes(colour = z))
print(my.plot)
```

And that should be that. You don't need to tell `geom_point()` what x and y are, because you already did that when you set up the plot.

Comment: Unless you mean you want to plot your `z` variable on the y-axis, in which case its `my.plot <- ggplot(data = my.data, aes(x = x, y =z)) + geom_point()`.

Comment: Thanks! But it's not what I want to do....I want to upload a file with a figure or something similar.. but I still don't have permission for that. But thanks anyway!